# Maven - make a report when failsafe crashes during execution

Tags: java, maven, selenium, maven-failsafe-plugin

I use Maven to make Integration test with Selenium, which run automatically.

I need to find a way to detect when failsafe crashes (when my integration test with selenium gets a fail), and make a report. How can I do that ?

At the end, I want to send a mail when the Integration test crashes.

Anyone have a solution or good idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its sounds like your looking for something which detects and reports on test failures.

Jenkins is widely used and covers a lot of what you are after. 
Jenkins runs on a per build basis via a build manager (maven, ant, dos scripts),
and takes actions based on the results of that build.

http://jenkins-ci.org/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `verify` goal of the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/).

Comment: Je n'ai pas réussi à trouver quelque chose de satisfaisant, du coup j'ai réaliser un petit code java qui réalise l'envoi de mail en cas de capture d'exception.